# writing PID of a command in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, pid

I have this command launched in a bash script:

`rsync -av $sourcedir/ $destdir/`

how do I store the PID for that specific command in a variable in the same script?

i tried with:

`rsync -av --stats  $sourcedir/ $destdir/ && pid=$(echo $$)`

but the pid reported for that operation in the log file differs from the one printed out echoing $pid

thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you want to know the PID of this command?  If you are running it synchronously, the process will have finished by the time you attempt to obtain its PID, and so the PID will no longer exist, or will refer to a different process.

Comment: `$$` is the process ID of the current shell, not the most recently run command. Also, `pid=$$` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rsync -av --stats $sourcedir/ $destdir/ & pid=$!
```

Note `&` usage here. You run commands in parallel.

If you make `rsync && pid=$!`, it is wrong, because the command (`rsync`) is already finished at the point where you make the assignment (`pid=$!`), so it is make no sense to save its pid in a variable for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The PID is stored in `$!` and you probably want to obtain the PID while the program is running, not after it has finished.

`rsync -av --stats $sourcedir/ $destdir/ & pid=$!`